# react.js confirmation modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, frontend

I was wondering if anyone knows the easiest way to create a delete(confirmation) modal in react.js? I have been playing around with a few things but cannot get my head around it.

The modal needs to pop up from a bin icon upon click. I am a complete beginner to react so I am struggling quite a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using https://github.com/GA-MO/react-confirm-alert -

```
yarn add react-confirm-alert
```

display.jsx:

```
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css'

const msg = `Item ${item.style} (barcode ${item.barcode}) is not 
  currently in this display. Do you want to add it?`

const addDialog = ({ onClose }) => {
  const handleClickedNo = () => {
    alert('clicked no')
    onClose()
  }
  const handleClickedYes = () => {
    alert('clicked yes')
    onClose()
  }
  return (
    <div className='add-dialog'>
      <h3>Add item to display</h3>
      <p>{msg}</p>
      <div className="add-dialog-buttons">
        <button onClick={handleClickedNo}>No</button>
        <button onClick={handleClickedYes}>Yes, add item</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}      

confirmAlert({ customUI: addDialog })
```

You can add your own custom css to override the defaults, e.g. I have:

```
/* override alert dialog defaults */
.react-confirm-alert-overlay {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.react-confirm-alert {
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 1em;
}
/* custom alert dialog styles */
.add-dialog h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
.add-dialog-buttons {
  float: right;
}
.add-dialog-buttons button+button {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

which looks like this -

[image: dialog]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this npm package. https://github.com/gregthebusker/react-confirm-bootstrap.

Once you have installed it, you can use it like this in your project.

```
<ConfirmationModal
    onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
    body="Are you sure?"
    confirmText="Yes"
    cancelText="No"
    title="Delete confirmation">
    <Button>Button Text</Button>
</ConfirmationModal>
```

I have been using this package in my project with a few modifications. But the default package should be more than enough for your use case.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Unfortunatley I cant install anything onto the server I am running this on at the moment.

Comment: No problem. In case you need any other help, you can join me on Slack here. https://code-slayers-den.slack.com/ . I recently created this group for fellow devs.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing for custom modal designing is `react-bootstrap`
React-bootstrap contain its own Modal component, which is can be molded according to your own custom design, while having `bootsrap` helps you with other designing things in your application too.
Modal Component is easy to use,handle & implement. By default it have its own cancel/ok buttons in it, you just need to implement and use.
here is the link:

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Hope that will help you.

Happy Coding!